# Including a .tag file for a library which itself includes a .tag file can provoke duplicate anchor warnings

Tags: doxygen

I have three libraries - libA, libB and libC.

libA has a .dox file, which contains the following anchors:

```
\section First_Section First Section 

\subsection First_Subsection First Subsection
```

libB includes the tag file for libA as follows: 
    @TAGFILES              =  $(DOXY_OUTPUT)/../libA/libA.tag=../libA

libC includes the tag files for libA and libB, as follows:

```
@TAGFILES              =  $(DOXY_OUTPUT)/../libA/libA.tag=../libA \ 
                               $(DOXY_OUTPUT)/../libB/libB.tag=../libB
```

However, when I run doxygen on libC in order to generate the documentation for libC, I see the following warning messages:

libB.tag: warning: Duplicate anchor First_Section found 
libB.tag: warning: Duplicate anchor First_Subsection found

It seems that, because libB uses the tagfile for libA, that when libC tries to use the tagfile for libB, it has in fact already obtained the anchors from libA and so it considers those it finds in libB relating to libA to be duplicates.

I am using Doxygen 1.8.10.

Comment: When cross linking please add other references as well: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793088 What happens when using doxygen 1.8.14 (I don't expect a difference though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example provided by OP. at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793088 OP. had no problem with version 1.8.13. My tests also revealed that with 1.8.14 there was no warning anymore.

Solution: upgrade to a newer version.